# bold face in title for variables put in with 'substitute'

Tags: r

That one should be really easy... How does one get the `i` (=1) in bold face in the title in the following plot (with only adjusting the argument `main`)?

```
i <- 1
plot(0~0, main=substitute(bold("foo"~i.~"bar"), list(i.=i)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
i <- 1
plot(0~0, main=substitute(bold("foo"~i.~"bar"), list(i.=as.character(i))))
```